# MOQ - how to mock an interface that needs to be cast to another interface?

Tags: unit-testing, inheritance, interface, moq

what I want to do is construct a moq for I1 - which is fine ... however in the course of the method that I am testing that uses this mock I need to cast it to I2 in order to access some properties that are not on I1

```
Interface I1 
{ int AProperty{get;set;}}

Interface I2
{int AnotherProperty{get;set;}}
```

I then have some objects

```
Class O1 : I1 {}
```

and

```
Class O2 : O1 , I2 {}
```

the problem is that when i have an instance of a I2 implementing object I can cast it to I1 in order to access the methods that are implmented through that interface. In code this is not a problem and everythign works as expected.

The only problem comes when writing a unit test on that class.

The interfaces also expose a method called GetNewInstance which returns an initialised instance of the the implementing object cast into the IGetNewInstance interface ... i can usually mock this fine and make it return itself (and so I keep working with the mock object).

however when you try to cast this returned object of type I2 into I1 a null reference results - this makes sense as the mock object that implements I2 does not inherit from anything that inherits I1.

the question is how can i force the mock object to inherit from both I1 ansd I2 at the same time?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The way I understand you, you want to create a mock that implements two interfaces. With Moq, that is as simple as this:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>(); // Creates a mock from IFoo
mock.As<IBar>(); // Adds IBar to the mock
mock.As<IBar>().Setup(m => m.BarMethod()).Returns(new object()); // For setups.
```

Now, you can set up expectations and use your mock as you would normally use the object implementing both `IFoo` and `IBar`.

For your `GetNewInstance` method, you can just set up an expectation that returns the mock itself.

Comment: BTW to anyone reading when you do the setups you have to use the mock.AS<IBAR>.Setup(......)

Comment: Awesome, this works great. If you need to do the .Setup you can do it all in one line, you don't need to do the As<> on it's own first, you can just do it all in one line.

Comment: Is there a way to do this setup as a non-interface?

Comment: I actually do not use Moq anymore. I far it far far simpler just to manually create mocks - it also forces me to really think about what i am doing. When using something like resharper / rider with decent refactor tools it is so much simpler - it helps people realise that they are often not testing anything of substance.